# How to display the accessed (thru for loop) objects in array in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I had a form from HTML. The input data from form will go to the multidimensional array that I made in JS. Then I will use for loop to access the objects in array in order to display the object values in the HTML div. In html, it only displays `[object,object]`

```
var data = [];  
var i, item;

function myForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var bday = document.getElementById("bday").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var pWord = document.getElementById("pWord").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var age = document.getElementById("bday").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML
    var ageValue;
    var Bdate = document.getElementById("bday").value; //Getting Values from the form of HTML and calculating the age of the user
    var Bday = +new Date(Bdate);
    ageValue = ~~ ((Date.now() - Bday) / (31557600000));
    var theBday = document.getElementById("age");
    theBday.innerHTML = ageValue;


    var userObject = {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        bday: bday,
        email: email,
        pWord: pWord,
        ageValue: ageValue,

    }; //The values i get from my Input in html. The userObject will be in a array data[]
       data.push(userObject);

      for (i=0 ; i <data.length ; i++){
        for (item in data[i]){
            document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML=(item + data[i][item]);  //I'm trying to display the details from my form but the only thing show up is [object,object]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html

Comment: @mabhijith95a10

<body>
  <div id="format">
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myForm(event)">
  Name:
   <input type="text" id="name"></input></br>
  Phone Number:
   <input type="phone" id="phone"></input></br>
  Birthday:
   <input type="date" id="bday" ></input></br>
  Email:
   <input type="email" id="email"></input></br>
  Password:
   <input type="password" id="pWord"></input></br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="myData()" >Submit</button>
  </form>
    <p id="demo3" onsubmit="myForm(event)"></p>
 </div>
</body>

Comment: @mabhijith95a10 sorry i cant post it as a code,

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the above code is this line

```
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML=(item + data[i][item]);
```

which is replacing the content of `div#demo3` instead of appending so use this line instead

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=(item + data[i][item]);
```

Here is a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4b9jfkt/1/).

I did not face `[object,object]` problem. If you can post your html code problem can be identified easily.

**Update**

Clear the content of `div#demo` before running the loop again.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
```

Check this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4b9jfkt/2/).

Comment: can i append the results in another div? Actually your code works, but the output duplicates whenever i try to submit another user data

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="navBar">
        <a href="signUp.html">HOME</a>
        <a href="signUp.html">LOG IN</a>
        <a href="signUp.html">SIGN UP</a>
    </div>

    <center><h1>Sign Up Form</h1></center></br></br>

<div id="format">
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="myForm(event)">
    <b>Name:</b></br>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" required="required" value="1234"></input></br>
    <b>Phone Number:</b></br>
        <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" maxlength="20" required="required" value="123"></input></br>
    <b>Birthday:</b></br>
        <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" required="required" value="2010-05-02"></input></br>
    <b>Email:</b></br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" required="required" value="asasa@yahoo.com"></input></br>
    <b>Password:</b></br>
        <input type="password" name="pWord" id="pWord" maxlength="50" required="required" value="fgfghff"></input></br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="myData()" >Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>

    </form>
    <div>
            <p id="demo" onsubmit="myData()"></p>

        </div>
    <div id="result" onsubmit="myForm(event)">  
        <center>Result</center>
        Name:<p id="name1"></p>
        Phone Number:<p id="phone1"></p>
        Birthday:<p id="bday1"></p>
        Email:<p id="email1"></p>
        Password:<p id="pWord1"></p>
        Age:<p id="age"></p>    

    </div>
        <div id="sample">           
            <p id="demo3" onsubmit="myForm(event)"></p>
        </div>


</div>



</body>
```

Comment: @mabhijith95a10 Here's my html code
when i try your code, it works thanks. But the problem is that the display duplicates whenever i  try to submit again. I wish i could append another div for another user and the output is not duplicating the the first output